# How can I make my code more efficient in R - It's to repetitive

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have a question regarding the efficiency of my code. I have 9 data frames in my environment and for each of them I need to perform the same steps. The steps and the code is (only shown for two of the data frames):

```
CDL <- aggregate(A$Frequency, by=list(Category=A$Words), FUN=sum)
wordcloud(words = CDL$Category, freq = CDL$x, min.freq = 2,
      max.words=250, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"))

Ltd <- aggregate(B$Frequency, by=list(Category=B$Words), FUN=sum)
wordcloud(words = Ltd$Category, freq = Ltd$x, min.freq = 2,
      max.words=250, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"))
```

I first aggregate all the same words, sum their frequencies and then create a world cloud based on the aggregated results.

The object names in the environment start from 'A' and go all the way to 'I'. The variable 'Frequency' is just a number, the variable 'Words' contains a list of the words.

For the wordcloud: 
The variable 'Category' contains the unique words taken from the 'Words' variable and 'x' is the aggregated sum of Frequencies taken from 'Frequency'

Is there any way I could perform the same but without repeating my code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, defining a function and loop it should work!

```
word_cloud <- function(df) {
  temp <- aggregate(df[,"Frequency"], by=list(Category=df[,"Words"]), FUN=sum)
  result <- wordcloud(words = temp[,"Category"], 
    freq = temp[,"x"],
    min.freq = 2,
    max.words=250,
    random.order=FALSE,
    rot.per=0.35,
    colors=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"))
  return(result)
}

input_list <- list(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)

for (df_inp in input_list) {
  word_cloud(df_inp)
}
```

I do not know the output mode of wordcloud(), so you may want to save the results to a list or plot it! I hope that helps!

Comment: The loop would better be done with the `apply` family instead of a `for` loop: `output_list <- lapply(input_list, word_cloud)`

Comment: The output of the world cloud just shows the image appearing, On the top of the image it says 'R Graphics: Device 2 (Active)'. Your code did the job, the only problem is that each image appears and then the next one takes over the previous image, it does not gives me enough time to save the image before displaying the next one. Normally I have to click on file, save to save the image.

Comment: One could use the name of the data frame to set up an output graphics file with `png()` prior to generating the graphic, and `dev.off()` afterwards to close the file.

Comment: In the loop, you can at the first line `filename <- paste0(substitute(df_inp), ".png")` followed by `png(filename = filename)`. Insert `dev.off()` at the last line of the loop and you will be saving the plots as png files in your working directory.

Comment: Thanks @KenS. I tried what you said and it only saved the world cloud for the last object in 'input list'. I think instead of creating one for each and saving it, It created one and then override the image with the next object in input list; hence at the end I only found the last one.        This is the full code [link] 'for (df_inp in input_list) {
  filename <- paste0(substitute(df_inp), ".png") 
  png(filename = filename)
  word_cloud(df_inp)
  dev.off() 
}'

Comment: Try to replace the filenames with something unique. For example, say `i <- 1` before the loop. Inside the loop, replace the old `filename` line with `filename <- paste0("plot_", i, ".png")`. After the line with `dev.off()` place an additional line `i <- i+1`

Comment: Yes I think that should fix the issue. I have not tried yet but will try later. Thanks @KenS.